# Compile a library without checking references

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was given a legacy solution which is not buildable due to broken references, code etc.

There are about 50 library-projects and I need to make a slight change to one of these library, then compile this only library and use it in production where a working system is deployed.

I don't want to make a long way making the solution buildable, fixing hundreds of issues etc.

Is there a way to skip reference checking and build the only needed library?

Comment: Assuming the library you want has no dependency issues, you can right-click on it and select `build`.

Comment: @keyboardP unfortunately many of it's references are not buildable

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do this by (taking a backup and then)

1. Collect together all of the dll/assemblies
2. Remove all of the projects that don't build from the solution
3. Then include the DLL's directly as a reference via the Add Reference -> Browse and selecting the DLL's

[image]

This will only really work if you can get the right DLL's that exactly match the source version you are trying to rebuild. Whilst this should always be the case (version control etc) - experience tells me that this can be the hardest part.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it will take a lot of refactoring, but the only way I can think is in programing against interfaces an use Dependency Injection to supply mocks instead the real implementations.. But it will affect the whole application..

Comment: Thanks, but I consider refactoring as an overkill in order to change few lines

Answer (score 1):

If you have the binaries from the working system it may be easier to decompile them into build able projects than trying to find the errors in the existing broken source code base.

But this is basically a mess because you must be methodical and apply your patches to the existing broken system , so that when the other issues are fixed and the build resumes from that code base, your changes are not lost in the decompiled branched off system.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have working dlls for each project, then either

**Method 1**

Copy the project would want to compile (call this project1) into another solution, and replace all references to the other projects with the existing working dlls.
This should allow you to recompile project1.

You then may need to re-compile any projects that depend on project1. To do this, you then need to copy each project that depends on project1 into you new solution and replace the references to other projects with the existing working dlls (apart from references to Project1).

Then you need to repeat the procedure with any projects that you copied across in the above stage and replace any references to projects that are not currently part of your new solution with the working dlls.

And repeat this procedure recursively until no further dependencies exist.

**Method 2**

Copy everything across into a new solution and try to build the project and look at the first project that fails to compile - (call this project2)
This project should not depend on any of the other projects, so you can remove this project from your solution (or set your solution not to compile it). Then go through all your other projects and remove any references to project2 and instead replace with with a reference to your existing dll (project2.dll).
Then try to build your project again and repeat the procedure with the next project that fails to build. And repeat for each project that fails to build.

When you have finished, your solution will depend on projects that can be built or else the existing dlls.

**Finally (and importantly)**.

Regardless of whether you use Method 1 or 2, you need to make sure the finished output is consistent. If, for example, you are using an old copy of project2.dll and a newly compiled project project that uses project2.dll but is expecting a newer version of project2, then you could get a buildable program that is logically incorrect. However, if there have been no changes to the source code, then the output should be correct.